# How does one pass a constructor method to another method and invoke it there?

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

I am trying to avoid repeating the same code in the clone methods of two classes, one inheriting from the other. My current approach is to put the code that is common to both classes in the (non-static) clone method of the base class and call it from the extending class. To do this I am trying to pass the constructor of the extending class to the base class so it can be invoked there. Here is a simplified example of what I am currently doing:

```
class S(object):
    """Base class"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def clone(self, constructor=None):
        if constructor is None:
            constructor = self.__init__
        cloned = constructor()
        # Expecting: cloned.a = 1, cloned.b = 7

        assert cloned is not None  # raises AssertionError
        cloned.a = self.a  # Set a to 2
        return cloned

class C(S):
    """Child class, extending Base"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 7

    def clone(self):
        cloned = super(C, self).clone(self.__init__)
        # Expecting: cloned.a = 2, cloned.b = 7

        cloned.b = self.b  # Set b to 8
        return cloned

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c1 = C()
    c1.a = 2
    c1.a = 8
    c2 = c1.clone()
```

My questions at this point are:

- Why is `None` returned when calling the `clone` method of the base class?
- Do I have to bind the method to a class in order to use it, using
  `types.MethodType` or `__get__`?
- What would you suggest as a better way to go?

Comment: Are you aware of the `copy` module?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, but I had made some false assumptions that made me believe that it wasn't good enough for what I was trying to do. It turns out that it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `__init__()` is often called the constructor in Python, it actually isn't.  It gets the instance passed in as the `self` argument, and it returns `None`.  The instance is constructed earlier by the `__new__()` method, which is the actual constructor.  You shouldn't pass in a reference to `__new__`, though.  It's much easier and more straightforward to pass in the type itself.

**Edit**: The right approach to implement a `clone` method is yet another one: Stick to the usual Python protocols, and implement [`__getstate__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) and [`__setstate__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) on your instances.  Then you can use the functions from the `copy` module to clone your instances correctly.

Comment: In other languages constructors also run in the context of already allocated memory and constructed, but not initialized object. What exactly is different in `__init__` that it is not a constructor? O_o

Comment: @BartoszKP The OP of this question was expecting that the constructor generates a new object and returns it, which it doesn't, and I answered to make this clear.  That said, there definitely are differences in the role of `__init__()` and a constructor in, say, C++.  The most important difference is that `__new__()` already returns a fully working object in a consistent state, in some case even an initialised one (e.g. for immutable types).  `__new__()` does significantly more than the allocator in C++, which is why I called it the "actual" constructor here.

Comment: What do you mean by "fully working"? Whether the object is "fully working" depends on the code in `__init__` and on base class, which can do exactly the same type of setup as in case of vtables in C++ (which you probably have in mind). For example, it is expected to explicitly call base's `__init__` from the subclass, so I wouldn't call it "fully working" in such case.

Comment: @BartoszKP I won't insist on this terminology – it's both reasonable to call `__init__()` the constructor and `__new__()` the constructor.  The wording in this answer may be too strong, but I don't really care – I mostly meant to answer the OPs question.

Comment: You're right, and I admit that it is a difference (not big, but worth mentioning). And, it's exactly what the documentation says (that these two together work as a constructor) :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your base class clone method is redundant.  Calling `self.__init__()` from any context will follow the MRO from the specific instance of the object, meaning that calling `clone()` on an instance of `C` will call `C.__init__()` from the code in `S` without specifying to use `c.__init__()` explicitly.

If what you want to do though is be able to customize `clone()` without necessarily creating an entirely new class, or have different behaviors depending on other factors, I'd suggest looking at the factory/builder pattern.

Also, specifically for `clone()` type operations, you might want to look at overloading `__copy__()`, `__getstate__()`, and `__setstate__()` and working with `copy.copy()` and `copy.deepcopy()` instead of implementing a new dialectical element.